# Control board powered up with reverse polarity. power transistor blown. Is this repairable?

Tags: transistors, pcb, thermal, repair

My dog chewed through the power cord. I 'repaired' it not paying attention to polarity. It was a 2A, 9V wall wart type power supply. The motherboard is from an elliptical exercise machine. The one transistor got obliterated. I thought it was going to be hard to remove and replace but when I snipped the 3 legs, the destroyed transistor and a thin thermal pad it was stuck to pulled off. I'm assuming that the black blobs came from thermal grease or similar? Anyway, is this even worth trying to fix? I can solder a bit and can get that same part, but the thermal pad (and its destruction) stuff is new to me. Thoughts appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Poor pup. Good thing it wasn't an AC line cord

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the black blobs are tar formed from the resin that was overheated.

one of them is covering the label for this part. it looks like it might start with U.

That's a good thing. because it means this burnt thing is probably a voltage regulator, and if that's the case it probably took all the energy from the wall wart, and is the only damaged part on the board.

the PCB is blackened and that black is carbon, so it probably now conducts electricity in places where it should not.  but as the voltage is low and the damage localised that's probably not going to significantly impede function.

but now the problem is choosing the right replacement. the marking on it 
seems to say L78xx but the last two digits are unreadable in the photo. however knowing the number is vital choosing the right part.

It's probably not L7805 as there's already one of those `U6` and it would be unusual to use two the same.9V is not enough for L7808 so the part is probably L7806, but that's just a guess.

Comment: It’s not impossible it’s another 7805- I’ve done that several times-eg. to separate digital and analog rails or to spread power dissipation.

Comment: I really appreciate the info. I'll try to figure out what that part is.